# How To Add a Constraint to a Type Constructor

Tags: haskell, servant

Consider the following data type:

```
data Get (statusCode :: Nat)
```

Actually, it's a simplified [type constructor from servant](https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/blob/bf824a388/servant/src/Servant/API/Verbs.hs#L26) which is then used in a type-level API like this:

```
type API = "users" :> Verb 'GET 200 '[JSON] [User]
```

For our purposes we can cut down the API to

```
type API = Get 200
```

Now, having a restriction of the status code being of kind `Nat` is too loose, allowing to define a non-existing HTTP status code:

```
type API = Get 999
```

Hence, the question: **Is there a way to restrict the set of naturals that can be applied to the `Get` type constructor?**

## What was Tried

*I'll omit all the pragmas and imports in the code samples for clarity.*

#### A different kind for `statusCode`

One obvious way to fix it would be to define a separate ADT for status codes and use it in place of `Nat` utilizing data type promotion.

```
data StatusCode = HTTP200 | HTTP201 | HTTP202
data Get (statusCode :: StatusCode)
```

However, this is a breaking change, which'd require to bump a major version and rewrite all the users' definitions. I doubt the benefit of restricted codes is worth it.

#### DatatypeContexts

This extension allows to have a straightforward constraint on our type variable

```
data IsStatusCode statusCode => Get (statusCode :: Nat)
```

but it requires users to add the constraint to all their declaration. Again, a breaking change. Besides, `DatatypeContexts` is deprecated.

#### Type Families

We could conditionally create `Get'` from the example below using type families, but for some reason declaring a type alias happily compiles. In order to get an error we need to construct a value of this type, which is also a breaking change.

```
data Get' (statusCode :: Nat) = Get

type family Get x where
  Get x = If (x <=? 600) (Get' x) (TypeError (Text "Invalid Code"))

type API1 = Get 200
type API2 = Get 999 -- compiles.

api :: Get 999 -- doesn't compile.
api = Get
```

Comment: The last one is, I think, equivalent to `type API2 = TypeError ...`. I argue that this _should_ compile, otherwise either 1) no code with a `TypeError` could type check, or 2) we can no longer substitute aliases and get equivalent programs (`type E = TypeError ... ; type X = If .. .. E` should be equivalent to `type X = if .. .. (TypeError ..)`, when `E` is not used later on). Note that I'm only guessing here -- I'm not an expert on how these type errors actually work.

Comment: I would say that restricting the set of status codes is not a great idea. The HTTP designers intended the status codes to be extensible and there are plenty of non-standard status codes out there (eg WebDAV). By restricting said codes you're making it impossible for users of your library to integrate with systems which use status codes you didn't anticipate. In the real world people need to be able to do that sort of thing.

Comment: You can encode all required codes like `type HttpStatusCodeOK = (200 :: Nat)` and then supply them into `Get`. This approach doesn't catch attempts to supply wrong codes but it documents the valid ones.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson if the constraint was imposed by, say, type classes, it'd be open for extension. You'd just have to create an `IsStatusCode` instance for your custom code.

Comment: If you want to go crazy on the type level magic then this paper: https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf defines type level less than/greater than operations.

Comment: I don't think your `DatatypeContexts` solution works the way you think it does: the constraints are simply tacked on when trying to use any of its constructors, so `undefined :: Get 999` compiles just fine. That said, I am very confused as to why the last example even needs a value of the type... I would've expected `api  = undefined` to return a type error too. My gut feeling is that this is an error...

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11990#comment:7) example seems to suggest this is a bug...

Comment: I'm thinking in GHC 8 you can probably do this with `TypeInType`, since you can promote GADTs.

Comment: @dfeuer, I tried that too and got an error about an illegal constraint in a promoted constructor.

Comment: There are also constraints in kinds, which look promising, but I could make it work either. https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#constraints-in-kinds

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a solution, then discuss the other possibilities (which appear to not have panned out):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators, TypeInType, GADTs #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Nat, type (<=))
import Data.Proxy (Proxy(..))
import Data.Kind (type (*))

data Get (statusCode :: Nat) :: (statusCode <= 600) => *

type API1 = Get 900 -- compiles
type API2 = Get 200 -- compiles

api1 :: Proxy (Get 900) -- doesn't compile
api1 = Proxy

api2 :: Proxy (Get 200) -- compiles
api2 = Proxy
```

No type families needed, no need to ever drop down to the value level. The type synonyms, however, will compile just fine. *Using* a type synonym of an invalid `Get` will lead to a compile time crash at the usage site. I reckon this is as good a solution as you can hope for. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

---

Next, just some thoughts on the other approaches:

#### `DatatypeContexts`

This one will never work: besides being deprecated, all this does is add the constraint to constructors. You specifically indicated you *don't* want to have to construct anything of the type, so this is pointless. The new GADT syntax fixes this ambiguity - the constraints are now clearly bound to the data or type constructors.

#### Type Families and `TypeError`

I believe this should work, and without having to construct a value of the type. (So the following should be fine:)

```
data Get' (statusCode :: Nat)

type family Get x where
  Get x = If (x <=? 600) (Get' x) (TypeError (Text "Invalid Code"))

api2 :: Proxy (Get 200) -- should compile.
api2 = Proxy

api1 :: Proxy (Get 999) -- shouldn't compile, but currently does
api1 = Proxy
```

I am motivated to believe this should work based on the [example](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11990#comment:7) in this trac ticker. Something here is clearly not behaving as it should: even if I replace the call to the type function `If` with the `TypeError` itself, still nothing gets triggered - it appears that `TypeErrors` that aren't top-level still cause some problems.

On the other hand, I am really unsure what the behaviour of `TypeError` in `type` synonyms *should* be, although I'm inclined to say that `type API1 = Get 999` should not compile, since `type API1 = TypeError (Text "error")` doesn't.